# jQuery autocomplete function not working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I have a page where a user can click a button which says "Add a Skill" and then it should display an input box where you type in your skill, it should display another input box where your skill level should appear and then a horizontal slider where you select your skill level.

I have table in the database called 'skill_list' which has two columns: id and name. The name field will contain thousands of skills in it which you can select from.

I also need the functionality for it to only post the form if the skill exists in the database.

**What I am asking is how to get the autocomplete working with jQuery based on my current code or could someone rewrite it slightly for me?**

At the moment I have the following code and it throws up no errors in the firebug console and everything works aas normal but I'm really unsure what I have to do to get this working:

**skills.php - auto() function (controller)**:

```
public function auto(){

    $skill = $_POST['skill-0'];

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from skill_list WHERE name LIKE "'.$skill.'%" ORDER by name ASC LIMIT 10');

    $data = array();

    if ( $query && mysql_num_rows($query) ){

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC) ){

            $data[] = array(

                'label' => $row['name'],
                'value' => $row['id']

            );

        }

    }

    echo json_encode($data);
    flush();

}
```

**skills.php (view)**

```
<form method="post" action="skills/add" id="container">  

<script>

$.fn.addSlide = function () {
return this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $num = $('.slide').length++,
        $name = $('<input type="text" class="inputField" id="autoskill" name="skill-' + $num + '" placeholder="What\'s your skill?"></div>'),
        $slide = $('<br><div class="slide" id="slider-' + $num + '"></div><br>'),
        $amt = $('<input name="amount-' + $num + '" id="amount-' + $num + '" class="inputField" readonly placeholder="Slide to select this skill level..."/><br>');
    $this.append($name).append($amt).append($slide);
    $slide.slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $amt.val(ui.value); 
        }
    });
});
}

$('body').on('click', '.addNew', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('#newFields').addSlide();
}); 

var count = 0;  

$(document).ready(function(){   

$('#autoskill').autocomplete({
    source:'skills/auto', minLength:2
});

$('.addNew').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#length').html(count);       
    count++;
});

$('.submitButton').click( function(event){
    $('#container').append('<input type="hidden" name="count" value="' + count + '">');
});

});



</script>

<button class="addNew submitButton"> Add a Skill </button><br>

<div id="newFields"></div>

<input type="submit" class="submitButton" value="Save Skills">

</form>
```

Hopefully someone can help, Thanks!

Comment: @putvande do you have any ideas as to what the problem could be?

Comment: Shouldnt it be `skills/auto.php` instead of `skills/auto`?

Comment: @putvande I'm using codeigniter so skills is the file and auto is a function within that file. Any suggestions on file path based on this?

Comment: Add console.log($('#autoskill')) before calling autocomplete function and tell me what is the output.

Comment: @WooCaSh it just displays this in the console with chrome [context: document, selector: "#autoskill", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]

Comment: @WooCaSh Any ideas on what the problem may be?

Comment: @AyeTry look on Xhr tab is any request is sended to this url: `skills/auto`.

Comment: @WooCaSh It is showing nothing in the XHR tab, is this under "network" and then "XHR"?

Comment: Even if you start typing in autocomplete box? Make sure that you type at least 3 characters.

Comment: @WooCaSh It's still displaying absolutely nothing. Really strange.

Comment: To make sure, do you included jQuery UI?

Comment: @WooCaSh these are the following that I have included: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: have you tried making a test JS array and setting that to the source instead of the codeigniter call

Comment: @SethCohen could you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: sure, inside of document.ready, comment out the block that attaches the autocomplete to autoskill, and try this instead:

var sampleData=['This','is','some','sample','data','to','test'];

 $( "#autoskill" ).autocomplete({source: sampleData});

and see if that has the desired result. also note that source must recieve JSON encoded data if you use a url as the source, so if sampleData works, then perhaps your codeigniter function is not returning what you expect it to be returning.

Comment: @SethCohen It seems that this is also not working as nothing appears at all. Is it maybe due to other functions in the script conflicting??

Comment: upon closer inspection of your code, I have a question for you: Are "slides" added after the document is loaded? The autocomplete is attached the input in the ready function, so any autoskills added after that will not have autocomplete. also, are you adding more than one of these inputs? if so use a class instead of an id.

Comment: @SethCohen yes so a user is able able to add as many new slides (skills) as they want after the page is loaded. Is there anyway of getting round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make $name into this

```
$name = $('<input type="text" class="inputField" id="autoskill-'+$num+'" name="skill-' + $num + '" placeholder="What\'s your skill?"></div>'),
```

then after

```
$this.append($name).append($amt).append($slide);
```

add

```
$('#autoskill'+$num).autocomplete({
    source:'skills/auto', minLength:2
});
```

and remove the autocomplete line completely from ur ready function

then for json make

```
 $data[] = array(

                'label' => $row['name'],
                'value' => $row['id']

            );
```

into

```
$data[$row['id']]=$row['name']
```

Comment: This still does nothing at all. Really strange that I ain't getting an indication of anything happening.

Comment: try $('.inputField').autocomplete({
    source:'skills/auto', minLength:2
}); instead

Comment: Okay, we are getting somewhere now but it is saying that <p>Message:      `Undefined index: skill-0</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/skills.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 86</p>` but it is returning that it is getting a response in XHR Request `URL:http://scotlandapprenticeships.com/skills/auto?term=HT` and a status code of 200

Comment: sounds like skills.php has some issue. to see if you can isolate the problem to skills.php, use my sampleData array from earlier as the source for autocomplete and see if it is functional

Comment: Yeah, I just did that there and it worked fine so it is definetely something wrong with the php script

Comment: Magic I managed to fix the other stuff in the PHP Script, many thanks couldn't have done it without you, much appreciated!!!!!